# IE JavaScript error onclick

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I'm relatively inexperienced in JavaScript, so this one is throwing me.  Any idea why this simple JavaScript would throw a Syntax error in IE?

```
<span class='floatleft' style='width:50px;'>
<a href='/Pages/ADI_Store.php?' 
class='hiddenlink' style='border:1px solid silver; width:100%;'
onclick="alert('Test')" >
<div class='floatleft'>Blue</div></a>
</span>
```

(Class 'hiddenlink' just hides the underscore, 'floatleft' floats the div left.)

Comment: not an the answer, but you "can't" put divs inside spans if you're aiming for a document that validates.

Comment: I know... but I'm getting a Syntax Error in the JavaScript console.  I assume it has something to do with the onclick="alert('Test')" but I can't see why....

Comment: Marc, that might be it.  I'll try changing that.

Comment: Your code looks fine could you please provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: It usually helps if you are more specific about *what* syntax error you are getting.

Comment: It seems working -> http://jsfiddle.net/zU2NL/ what error you are getting on console?

Comment: I don't think that's it... Your code is perfectly valid. http://jsfiddle.net/sircapsalot/kxkCH/   I opened that in ie 7 and runs fine.

Comment: Any chance that HTML is actually a string stored in a variable? If so, quoting/escaping might be the problem.

Comment: You might want to use a <script> tag to put your script in (use a function) and put `onclick="javascript:myFunction()"`

Comment: No, still throws a Syntax Error in the IE Console.  It says it's at the <div (now a <span) on the fifth line of the code.

Comment: Would you believe I'm not allowed to use JS functions unless absolutely necessary?

Comment: Quentin, the problem is that I'm using the built-in IE console, and all it say is Syntax error.